# Random parts on my model disappeared?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm new to blender. i was in the middle of sculpting my character and out of nowhere a bunch of faces disappeared and everything moved around. I applied all my modifiers so im not sure what happened..
[image]

even by undoing i couldnt get it back. this is the second time this has happened now. for ref here's what it looked like before
[image]

Could anyone tell me what happened and how to avoid it?

Comment: I think we need a little more details. What modifiers did you apply, and in what order were they in modifier stack, and in what order did you apply them?

Comment: I was using the mirror modifier and the subdivision surface modifier. the mirror modifier was first in the stack..i think i applied them in a random order for all the objects though..

Comment: Edit the question and provide all the info there so other people can quickly read everything without going through all the comments. The two modifiers you used should not cause this effect. You didn't press H by accident when in edit mode?

Comment: is this problem the same in the edit mode?